# testing on differnet resolution of my local computer

Tags: resolution

I have to test something for resolution which is 1280 X 1024, however, in my computer, it is at most 1280 X 800. 
How can I force it to 1280 X 1024 or any tools can make a virtual resolution?

Answer (score 2):

http://viewlike.us/ for webpages.

I don't know of any windows applications have such feature. So I guess you have to buy a bigger monitor.

Hope that helpes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Window Resizer" plugin for Google Chrome. It resizes the browser's window in order to emulate various resolutions

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hc=search&hcp=main

Answer (score 0):

Well i know Nvidia has an option like that to change the resolution of your display that is not exposed by the current monitor. IDK if you have NVIDIA but if you do just open the NVIDIA control panel and click on change resolution. then select customize and make sure the enable resolutions not exposed by the display.

UPDATE- you can also create a custom resolution as well in the same area. just click create custom resolution.